# ActionScript - loadBytes() example?

Tags: actionscript, loader

Can anyone tell me why you might use `loadBytes()` instead of a simple `load()`?

Answer (score 0):

From the ActionScript 3.0 Reference ([flash.system.LoaderContext](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html)):

> When loading a SWF file with the `Loader.loadBytes()` method, you have the same application domain choice to make as for `Loader.load()`, but it's not necessary to specify a security domain, because **`Loader.loadBytes()` always places its loaded SWF file into the security domain of the loading SWF file**.